# $2^{5-2}$ Design : Alias Structure

Tags: self-study, anova, interaction, experiment-design, fractional-factorial

$2^{5-2}$ Design

Design Generators: $D=AB\quad E=AC$

Defining Relation: $I=ABD=ACE=BCDE$

$$\text{Aliases}$$
$$A=BD=CE=ABDE$$
$$B=AD=ABCE=CDE$$
$$C=ABCD=AE=BDE$$
$$D=AB=ACDE=BCE$$
$$E=ABDE=AC=BCD$$
$$BC=ACD=ABE=DE$$
$$CD=ABC=ADE=BE$$
  But the alias structure in the book `Design and Analysis of Experiments` by Douglas C. Montgomery [Appendix XII (c)] is as following:

$$\text{Aliases}$$
$$A=BD=CE$$
$$B=AD=CDE$$
$$C=AE=BDE$$
$$D=AB=BCE$$
$$E=AC=BCD$$
$$BC=DE=ACD=ABE$$
$$CD=BE=ABC=ADE$$

Instead of $A+BD+CE+ABDE$, this is $A+BD+CE$ in the book and so on.

- Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think he's just not showing the 4- and 5-way interactions, for brevity and assuming people won't be too concerned about them

Answer (score 1):

Interaction of order IV or higher are not written because they are usually not significant. This principle is called "sparsity-of-effects principle" and it is explained in Design and Analysis of Experiments by Douglas C. Montgomery.